# Is it possible to save the girls in the alien goop or can you only kill them?

Tags: duke-nukem-3d, duke-nukem-3d-world-tour

I've picked up the new Duke Nukem 3D World Tour game for a nostalgic trip back to the 90s.  Throughout the game, you can find girls entangled or stuck inside of these alien cocoon things or as I called it, *goop*.

Is there anyway to free them or can you only kill them?  I've noticed that if you kill them, Duke will say something like "*Damn...*" making it seem like you could have saved them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the N64 version, you can save them. The number of babes saved is counted at the end of each level.

In the original Duke 3D, you can't. When interacting with them, they just say:

> Kill me.

I can't say for the Duke Nukem 3D World Tour game. Just try to use the "Use / Open door" button. I guess you already tried that and it didn't work, so I think you can't.

Comment: I actually haven't tried that, so I'll give it a shot.

Comment: They also just say "kill me." I never tried it until now.